# Back button shows password,username.Even though Cookies are expired?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-cookies

I am writing a custom login - On Logout i clear cookies

```
  public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        Session.Remove("Username");
        Session.Clear();
        if (Request.Cookies["Username"] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie usercookie = new HttpCookie("Username");
            usercookie.Expires =DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(usercookie);
            Response.Cookies.Set(usercookie);

        }
        if (Request.Cookies["Password"] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie usercookie = new HttpCookie("Password");
            usercookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(usercookie);
            Response.Cookies.Set(usercookie);

        }


       ViewBag.Error = "Logged out !!clear cookie";

       return RedirectToAction("Account","Home");
    }
```

Logout works fine ,but **on browser back button i get user name password back even though i cleared  cookies on logout.**

Comment: Is the browser caching the page? Also it's terrible practice to store credentials in cookies, as they are easily tampered with by an attacker.

Comment: Yes,But can i disable browser caching.I just wanted to store some value ,not necessarily credentials,Anyways how do you suggest to remember password other than cookies(it should be encrypted and saved ...but in cookies ...is it ??)

Comment: Try setting the OutputCache on the controller, with duration 0 and location none. Look at session cookies and ASP.Membership.

Comment: Thanks ,Yes we could set duration for outputcache

Comment: Did that but still i get the username on back button.I'll dwell into the matter more and then ask if anything

Comment: So , i looked a bit into ASP authentication in MVC 5.There's a problem!!It says a default database is created every time the project is created which stores user data .However i get two results in two systems using same visual studio.In one i am able to register a user and default database is created.However in another for some reason the database is not created,and the application breaks ,there is no connection string with the DB